# save output values in txt file in columns python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

My input value gives corresponding output values as;

```
my_list = []
for i in range(1,10):
     system = i,i+2*i
     my_list.append(system)
     print(my_list)

[(1, 3)]

[(1, 3), (2, 6)]

[(1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 9)]

[(1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 9), (4, 12)]
```

I want output stored in 2 columns; where `1,2,3`is first column elements and `3,6,9` for 2nd column.

```
(1 3)
(2 6)
(3 9)
```

so on... and then write store these values in text file. For text file, is it possible to generate text file as a part of script? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to save the element of `my_list` that has equal index with `i-1` (your range began at 1):

```
my_list=[] 
with open ('new.txt','w') as f:
 for i in range(1,10):
     system = i,i+2*i
     my_list.append(system)
     print(my_list)
     f.write(str(my_list[i-1])+'\n')
```

output:

```
(1, 3)
(2, 6)
(3, 9)
(4, 12)
(5, 15)
(6, 18)
(7, 21)
(8, 24)
(9, 27)
```

also as says in comments you don't need `my_list` you can do it with following code :

```
with open ('new.txt','w') as f:
 for i in range(1,10):
     system = i,i+2*i
     f.write(str(system)+'\n')
```

Comment: thanks. this saves only one value in out_put file as [(9, 27)].

Comment: thanks it works! i was editing my own script. thanks

Comment: welcome , so if you fide your answer , you can tell to community with [accepting an answer][1]
[1][http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235]

Comment: @Kasra : Why not `f.write(str(system) + '\n')` instead of `f.write(str(my_list[i-1])+'\n')` ?

Answer (score 3):

```html
file = open('out.txt', 'w')
print >> file, 'Filename:', filename  # or file.write('...\n')
file.close()
```

Basically, look at the "/n" and add it to variable it should append to the next line also:

use ("a" instead of "w") to keep appending to the file. The file will be in the directory you are building from.

Comment: with 'system\n' gives me 1 2 3 4 and system system system in 2nd column.

Comment: try to add a "+" sign inbetween variable and "/n" so: (variable+ '\n')